# PhpStorm 6: simple single line for cursor

Tags: phpstorm

I don't like using PhpStorm with the giant block as a mouse or keyboard cursor. I would like to switch it to a simple single line. My copy of PhpStorm on another computer does not look like this.

[image: Screenshot]

Any ideas how to disable it so it's a simple single line?

Answer (score 5):

Disable the **Use block caret** option in settings:

[image: block caret]

Comment: That will teach me not to poke things around just because I think I know what they mean lol, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Press Insert on your keyboard (again) ;)