# Phpstorm cursor issue Mac Os

Tags: phpstorm

I searched on Google, but nothing found , please how can I get the cursor format back  on PhpStorm, now it is bold and large,
I'm using Mac Osx 10.11

[image]

Your answer is appreciated

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [PhpStorm 6: simple single line for cursor](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18433867/4265352)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Preferences (<kbd>Cmd-,</kbd>) go to Editor -> General -> Appearance and uncheck "Use block caret"